# What logic function performs this IEEE Standard 91-1984 symbol?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics, programmable-logic

I'm thinking about copying network interface card for an old HP9000/300 series computer. These cards are insanely expensive on ebay these days (around 200USD), and i think that i could make one for half a price, and have a bit of fun replicating 6-layer board and building it. Schematics for this card are available, and there is only one custom component on it: it's a PAL chip for a specific logic function described on schematic with IEEE 91-1984 symbol:

[image]

In the process of building this card, i would have to write CUPL code for a GAL replacement of this PAL, and i need to understand exactly what logic function this symbol performs.
It looks like it's some kind of (multi stage?) shift register with a logic function, but unfortunately i can't understand how exactly i should read it. Maybe someone more profficient in reading these symbols can tell what exactly is happening here?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to work out the 32x64 fusable map by that picture. It's very close to [the datasheet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq08I.png). Forward motion may require you to acquire a careful understanding of the inputs and their behavior and the outputs and their required behavior and then work it out from that knowledge, as if you were also the designer.

Comment: The PAL16R8 (which is what you are showing) is a programmable device; it has register outputs and those are also fed back (whether the feedback is used or not depends on the programming). If you can find the fuse map for the device you *might* have a chance of replicating the functionality. Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pal16r6am.pdf

Comment: An IEEE symbol can't describe the complexity of a PAL16R8. Besides the good ideas already presented, you may want to attach a logic analyzer to a working board to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, in fact it looks that this is just a stock symbol of this PAL IC from datasheet, i haven't checked it before. So i won't be able to infer anything from this symbol, and i probably would have to acquire this card and either try to read fuse map from the IC, or analyze it's behavior with logic analyzer, and replicate that in GAL.

Comment: I don't there's any shift-register behavior going on in there. It looks to me as though it's decoding control lines from the bus - R/W-, A14, A15, etc. into internal control signals for the card - LANWR-, CPUGT-, etc. Likely mostly simple logic, with CLK- & EN used to gate and latch the signals.